# Pascal's triangle in k/q

Tags: kdb, q-lang, k

fibonacci is nice:

```
  f:|+\
5 f\1 1
```

but i haven't found a similar expression for Pascal's Triangle.  this is the best i can get:

```
q){x+\\x#1}6
1 1 1  1  1   1  
1 2 3  4  5   6  
1 3 6  10 15  21 
1 4 10 20 35  56 
1 5 15 35 70  126
1 6 21 56 126 252
1 7 28 84 210 462
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a pretty nifty one on the [q idioms page](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Qidioms#1007)

```
q)pt:{0+':x,0}
q)4 pt\ 1
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The [original Pascal triangle](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/PascalTriangle.shtml) was indeed rotated by 45° compared to the modern textbook version, so OP's solution is correct but can be improved for readability:

```
q)sums\[6;6#1]
1 1 1  1  1   1
1 2 3  4  5   6
1 3 6  10 15  21
1 4 10 20 35  56
1 5 15 35 70  126
1 6 21 56 126 252
1 7 28 84 210 462
```

For those who enjoy deciphering obfuscated q code, here is a lambda-free solution:

```
q)p:(sums\).(-1+;#[;1])@\:
q)p 3
1 1 1
1 2 3
1 3 6
```

Comment: and from the ': solutions:   ((+':),[;0]@)\[;1]   --   
from your link, Pascal's 'generator' (value 1) can be a parameter, too

Answer (score 1):

Heres a solution based off the fibonacci example on code.kx http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/

```
q)pascal:{{((+':)x),1}/[x;1]}
q)pascal 0
1
q)pascal 6
1 6 15 20 15 6 1

q){{((+':)x),1}\[x;1]}  7
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
```